# How to add text to a DIV from array of DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

`Var divs = $(".txt");` this will return a list of `divs` with a `class` txt .
I want to add text to a selected div for example :
`divs[4].html("Hello World");` this with return error saying `divs[4].html` is not a function. why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access a jQuery object by its DOM array index, you get the HTML element, not a jQuery object, which doesn't have the `html()` function. Use the [`eq(n)` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead:

```
$(".txt:eq(4)").html("Hello World");
```

Comment: @Adham - You should be able to do `$(divs[4]).html('blah blah')`.

Comment: @João `eq` is [0-based](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). I guess you confused it with `nth-child`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Yes, thanks, I was looking into the man page of `nth-child`.

Comment: I use DOM references all the time, and it is typically faster than pulling up a jQuery object to get the `id`. `this.id` also is so much *better* than `$(this).attr('id', 'whatever')`. It is somewhat misunderstood, but it solves several performance and efficiency problems if used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `divs[0]` is giving you a DOM reference, *not* a jQuery object. So, pass that to the jQuery function (`$()` is shorthand for `jQuery()`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $('.txt');

    $(divs[4]).html('this one');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/unu8g/

Note as well the use of `$(document).ready()`, which will wait until the DOM is accessible. `$(window).load()` will suffice for this as well, although it may fire after `onDOMReady`.

Answer (score 0):

The non jQuery way:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("txt")[4].innerHTML = "banananana!";
```

*Just a side note: I'd suggest learning basic browser javascript before moving to libraries. 
 It will give you an understanding of how such libraries work and will keep you from being 'locked in' to a specific few*